# Layout for Cytoscape (JavaScript) Compound Nodes Makes "Containers" Too Large

Tags: cytoscape.js

How can I make the "container" nodes in a Cytoscape Compound Graph smaller? The "cose" layout makes them gigantic for my graph, wasting an extreme amount of space. How can I "style" such container nodes to be a more reasonable size for the "child" nodes contained within it?

Answer (score 0):

The size of compound parent nodes is a function of the position and dimensions of its child nodes.  Thus, you can control parent node size via layout.  You can try experimenting with the parameters of the existing layouts or you can even write your own.

In general, you have to experiment with the parameters of a layout to get the visual results you want.  It can not be done automatically on the layout side.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I "experiment with the parameters of the existing layouts"?